# HttpClient GetAsync disposes Webjob handler

Tags: .net, azure, async-await, azure-webjobs, dotnet-httpclient

I'm implementing an **Azure WebJob** which, when triggered by a **Service Bus Message**, performs an **async API call** to an external web service. After executing the web request, something odd happens to my webjob and the **inputMessage has been disposed** before the end of the method.
Below is a basic example demonstrating the problem + output.

```
public async void HandleTestQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%TestQueue%")] BrokeredMessage inputMessage) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message {inputMessage.MessageId}.");

    Console.WriteLine("Starting web request.");
    await TestHttpClientAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished web request.");

    await inputMessage.CompleteAsync(); // --> Exception occurs here
    Console.WriteLine($"Completed message {inputMessage.MessageId}.");
}

private async Task TestHttpClientAsync() {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://google.com");
    Console.WriteLine($"Got response, statuscode={response.StatusCode}.");
}
```

Console output:

```
Executing: 'ProblemTestHandler.HandleTestQueueMessage' - Reason: 'New ServiceBus message detected on 'TestQueue'.'
Received message a17cc4fce8c74b3c9f1b8f1a73b4ba1b.
Starting web request.
Executed: 'ProblemTestHandler.HandleTestQueueMessage' (Succeeded)
Got response, statuscode=OK.
Finished web request.

Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: BrokeredMessage has been disposed.
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.ThrowIfDisposed()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.BeginComplete(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.Parallel.TaskHelpers.CreateTask(Func`3 begin, Action`1 end, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Wkb.eInvoicing.Worker.Handlers.ProblemTestHandler.<HandleTestQueueMessage>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Dev\eInvoicing\src\Wkb.eInvoicing.Worker\Handlers\ProblemTestHandler.cs:line 43
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

As you can see in the output, my JobHost container thinks the method successfully finished right after the execution of the *httpClient.GetAsync()* method:

```
Starting web request.
Executed: 'ProblemTestHandler.HandleTestQueueMessage' (Succeeded)
Got response, statuscode=OK.
```

When I replace the web request by a non-async alternative (e.g. using RestSharp), the problem does not occur. Any ideas what could be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: You should almost never use async void

Comment: Instead of `async void`, try using `async Task` And have a look at [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more info on why to avoid `async void`

Comment: Well.. making the handler async Task fixed the problem. Sad typo which was overlooked every other time. Thanks! If any of you could post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should almost never use `async void` unless you are writing a event handler, you should be using `async Task` instead, this lets the system know that your webjob is not complete yet so it will not try and force shutdown the resource before it is complete.